# Is possible use instream to clamd from shell?

Tags: anti-virus

Someone would point me how to use the clamd daemon in an remote server to scan files?

The cenario is:

Two Servers (**Server A** - *application like pure-ftpd*, **Server B** *clamav runing*)

Server A send one or more files to Server B verify

Using all in one box I already have it working with the CallUploadScript from pure-ftpd and the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/clamdscan --multiscan --fdpass --remove --quiet --no-summary "$1"
```

But, have no Idea about the steps to get same effect using an remote server

Comment: Please use a search engine. [First hit](https://bytesandbones.wordpress.com/2017/04/26/clamav-clamdscan-using-remote-clam-server-via-tcp/) when searching for [clamd remote](https://www.google.com/search?q=clamd+remote) seems to show the necessary configuration already.

Comment: The "First hit" and other's I have found, did not work, so ask in groups or sites like this one would be an option. I don't know why people spend they time judging or making useless answers if does not gonna help...

Comment: In this case you should provide what exactly you've tried and what you expected to happen and what happened instead instead of just asking broadly how to do this. Otherwise you will likely get only the information you've already tried, i.e. you get information you don't need while at the same time wasting the time of others who are trying to help you with information you already know.

Comment: @Wisdown the fact that a solution did not work is a *very* important detail to include. First, so that people don't waste their time offering you solutions that you already know won't work, and second, *how* it doesn't work helps to refine what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The point I was missing was basically on **Server A**.

Just added in the clamd.conf from **Server A**

```
TCPAddr IP of Clam Server (Not the local one)
TCPSocket Port of Clam Server (Not the local one)
```

The docs does not explain about use those 2 parameters on client for specify the server...

And have changed the upload script to

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/clamdscan --multiscan --fdpass --remove --quiet --no-summary --stream "$1"
```

After that, on **Server B**, can confirm in clamdtop the scans occours.

PS.: No need start Clamd or freshclam daemon on **Server A**, just use the client.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what Steffan's "top hit" says to do but you said it didn't work. Is there some detail that's different?